# getServletContext().getRealPath("") returning null in WebSphere Application Server Liberty

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I was previously using Tomcat v9.0 in local environment, while using

> getServletContext().getRealPath("")

to retrieve the path, server returned

> ....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\WebApp\

However as client runs WebSphere Application Server Liberty i installed the same on my machine, but the same code that returns a path in Tomcat, returns

> null

in Websphere environment. Could you help me understands as to why this happens and how will I get the path in Websphere environment. Also I have checked the following link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=eb04c8ae-02d4-421b-af2c-2ef626a3db1b&ps=50&tags=&query=&filter=&sortBy=&order=asc, yet couldn't find a solution.

Comment: How is the code deployed to both?

Comment: It isn't deployed on both I have stopped Tomcat temporarily to run Websphere. Thats how I can check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did get the path in the Websphere environment. In Websphere, it is required that we have to give a '/' instead of empty string i.e

> getServletContext().getRealPath("/")

instead of

> getServletContext().getRealPath("")

I am not sure if it holds true for all the cases, but it worked fine in my machine.

Comment: Yes, in addition you will need expanded war, so either set the `<applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>` if you just put applications in the `dropin` folder, or expand the war in the `apps` folder and add them to the `server.xml`. It will not work if the app will be kept in the packed form as archive.